# Is chat on this site down?

Tags: discussion, chat, outage

For some reason chat is showing a Runtime Error everytime I try to open [it](https://chat.stackexchange.com/). The message displayed reads:

> **Server Error in '/' Application.**
>
> **Runtime Error**
>
> *Description:* An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

Am I the only one experiencing this? Or is chat down for some maintenance?

Comment: chat seems down everywhere.

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors.

Comment: so wierd. I'm still seeing those across chat. Caching?

Comment: Works for me here (AU).

Comment: I'm in SG. Which should be between you and the US ;p

Comment: It's basically working for me, but I'm having some trouble with the associated moderator tools, so _something_ seems fishy about the chat system.

Comment: I'm in India and it's not working here. However I turned on my free VPN and set my location to USA. Now chat seems to be working fine! Any idea on why this might be the case?

Comment: and. It works on my phone and not my fixed connection. 0_0

Comment: Now it seems to have come back. Working perfectly.

Comment: Can you confirm it still works @AritraDas